# ¿Por qué getsizeof() no devuelve el verdadero tamaño en bytes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sizeof

Tengo entendido que la función `getsizeof()` devuelve el tamaño de un objeto en bytes. Ahora bien, estoy creando cadenas de caracteres aleatorias con los diferentes módulos de *PyCrypto*, y los tamaños no coinciden.

Un ejemplo:

```
import sys
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto import Random

secret = Random.new().read(30)
hs = SHA256.new()
hs.update(secret)
key = hs.digest()
print sys.getsizeof(key)
```

Ese `getsizeof()` devuelve un valor de 69, cuando el tamaño en bytes del `digest` de SHA256 es 32 según la propia documentación de la biblioteca.

¿Por qué ocurre esto? ¿Es posible que `getsizeof()` no funcione correctamente fuera de las bibliotecas estándar de Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) retorna el los **bytes ocupados por el objeto** en memoria. `digest` retorna un objeto `str` nativo de Python y `sys.getsizeof` retorna lo que este objeto al completo ocupa en memoria, lo que no equivale a lo que ocupa la cadena (secuencia de caracteres) que contiene.

El error de concepto viene por creer que `str` es solo una secuencia de bytes (caracteres ASCII), un tipo de dato al estilo de `char` en C, cuando es un objeto como todo en Python (más similar a `std::string` de C++ salvando las distancias). No hay que confundir el número de elementos contenidos en el string y lo que estos ocupan en memoria, con lo que el objeto `str` ocupa en memoria en su totalidad. Si vemos parte de la [implementación](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Include/stringobject.h#l35) de cpython de la clase `str`(Python 2.7):

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    long ob_shash;
    int ob_sstate;
    char ob_sval[1];

    /* Invariants:
     *     ob_sval contains space for 'ob_size+1' elements.
     *     ob_sval[ob_size] == 0.
     *     ob_shash is the hash of the string or -1 if not computed yet.
     *     ob_sstate != 0 iff the string object is in stringobject.c's
     *       'interned' dictionary; in this case the two references
     *       from 'interned' to this object are *not counted* in ob_refcnt.
     */
} PyStringObject;
```

vemos que, además del `char` (que contiene la cadena junto al carácter de terminación de cadena `\0`), tenemos un `int`, un `long` y [`PyObject_VAR_HEAD`](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Include/object.h#l90) que ocupan su espacio en memoria. A esto hay que sumarle, por ejemplo, la sobrecarga ocasionada por el recolector de basura encargado de manejar la memoria asignada a ese objeto. Por lo tanto, `sys.getsizeof` retorna lo que ocupa el objeto en memoria al completo, que es siempre algo más que la secuencia de caracteres.

Un objeto string tiene una sobrecarga inicial de entorno a 37 bytes (puede variar dependiendo del sistema). Es decir, una cadena vacía (`str`) ya ocupa 37 bytes en memoria. Por cada carácter añadimos un byte, por lo que en nuestro caso tenemos 37 + 32 =
69 bytes.

Dado que lo que quieres es obtener los bytes que ocupan en memoria la cadena y que `str` almacena precisamente bytes (ASCII) basta con que uses `len`:

```
>>> len(key)
32

>>> sys.getsizeof(key)
69
```

Hay que recordar que estamos tratando con objetos, un `int`, un `float`, `str` son objetos, lo cual conlleva cierta sobrecarga además de lo que ocupan los datos que almacenan en si mismos. Esto no es exclusivo de Python, volviendo a C++, no es de extrañar que un objeto `std::string` que supuestamente almacena una cadena de 100 bytes nos retorna que ocupa 8 bytes en memoria, no es magia, solo que el objeto se limita a almacenar por ejemplo un puntero (a la cadena propiamente dicha) y un entero (almacenando el tamaño de la cadena por lo general) pero no la propia cadena, la cual maneja de forma dinámica en memoria (dependiendo de la implementación del compilador). Con esto quiero decir que hay que ser muy cuidadoso cuando estamos tratando con objetos y queremos interpretar lo que ocupan en memoria.